# Responsive Top Nav Bar Moving Up Bug

Tags: html, css, header, navigation, navigationbar

Just started coding a website for myself.. still trying to figure how to do stuff, I got stuck with this annoying little thing, 
and I really want to fix it.
I have the following HTML & CSS codes,
The problem is when I click on the Nav Bar Icon it opens up a little bit higher for some reasons...

[image: you can see the nav bar goes up a little bit and doesn't stay in place]

HTML

```
<header class="topNav" id="topResNav">

    <a>DANIEL SHALAR</a>

    <nav>
    <a>MIX SHOW</a>
    <a>MUSIC</a>
    <a style="color:gray;">HOME</a> 
    </nav>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ResNav" onclick="myResNav()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>

</header>
```

CSS

```
/* Responsive Header */

header .ResNav{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    header nav a{display: none;}

    header a.ResNav{
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    }

    .topNav.responsive {position: relative;}

    .topNav.responsive .ResNav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    }

    .topNav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    }
}
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
<script>
function myResNav() {
    var x = document.getElementById("topResNav");
    if (x.className === "topNav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topNav";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When clicking on the nav icon, you're applying a new class to it, and seeing it shift because you're changing it to `position: absolute;`. This takes the icon out of the relative page flow. As well, using `top:0` and `right:0` puts the icon in the top-right of the container, which is different than the original position of the icon.

There's a few things you can try:

**Try setting no values:**
For starters, try not having `right` or `top`, and see what happens. Depending on other factors, you may get lucky. I'm saying this for others, not for your specific case.

**Match padding values:**
The obvious thing to do... match the values for `top` and `right` to what the padding is for the parent container --- or --- just tweak the values by eye-balling it. For example, if the parent container has `padding:1em`, then you'll use `top:1em` and `right:1em` on the icon. You can use pixel values too if you wish.

**Use Javascript:**
A more advanced technique is to use additional Javascript to detect the original page position of the relative element, and then apply that as `top` and `right` values which take affect when switching it to `position:absolute;`. Make a function with this and it'll be especially useful if you're changing relative/absolute position on many elements.

You'd use something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("my_menu_icon");
var elPosition = el.getBoundingClientRect();
el.style.right = br.right + 'px';
el.style.top = br.top + 'px';
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this big explanation!